# ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here when trying to use UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sql-update

I have written this code in Oracle APEX:

```
UPDATE employee SET total_cost = (SUM(c.price) 
FROM course c, schooling s
WHERE 
s.id_employee_schooling = id_employee AND s.id_course_schooling = c.id_course);
```

and it tells me that

> group function is not allowed here.

I found out that I cannot use `sum` and `WHERE` together but I don't know how to write this code in another way. Any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot the `SELECT` keyword in your subquery.

```
UPDATE employee
       SET total_cost = (SELECT sum(c.price)
                                FROM course c
                                     INNER JOIN schooling s
                                                ON s.id_course_schooling = c.id_course
                                WHERE s.id_employee_schooling = id_employee);
```

I also changed you implicit join to an explicit one for better readability.

But it also looks like what you're about to do shouldn't be done at all. `total_cost` seems to store redundant data which can cause inconsistencies. So the physical column `total_cost` should be dropped altogether. When you need that value when querying the employees get it from the other tables with joins or subqueries. That way the values are always right. You can also crate a view to make this more convenient.